# How to show price in drop down list using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to show the price in the drop down list from the following code, however it is showing the product name and not the price:

```
<?php
  //-----------------------PROCESSOR---------------------------
    $query="SELECT product_name, price FROM processor";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $options="";
    echo "<select name='processor' value=''>
    <option>Please Select A Processor</option>";

    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<option value='".$nt['price']."'>".$nt['product_name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide an example in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
echo "<option value='".$nt['price']."'>".$nt['product_name']."</option>";
```

with

```
echo "<option value='".$nt['price']."'>".$nt['price']."</option>";
```

Have a look at the documentation:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: So write echo "<option value='".$nt['price']."'>".$nt['product_name']." - ".$nt['price']."</option>";